# Proposal for another Mage stackday on Mid April 2015

Tags: support, site-evaluation, magestackday

First,congrats to all,as we are reached all 74% answer rate.But need to increase our answer rate to near 80%.
So need another stackday on mid  of April 2015.
I am requesting to @Marius and @Sander and @Anna ,please arrange another stackday.
You guys have done a great job on last Mage stack day.

Need help from all and Please give suggestion from all

Comment: I'm all aboard with this. But I have one correction. Anna and Sander are the masterminds behind MageStackDay. I barely did something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for your post and the kind words. We're now on 75% and we hope we can keep momentum to raise it even higher. As Ben said not only the answered rate should go up but preferably the overall commitment of more and more developers to actively participate on the forum. MageStackDay alone will not 'save' the forum, only when we have users daily answering, voting, closing etc this forum has a change of being the awesome place to share knowledge we want it to be.

Now on a MageStackDay for April. We would love to another one soon but organizing a MageStackDay takes up a lot of time and effort. To give you an idea for the last 3 or 4 weeks Anna and I support by David Manners and Marius Strajeru have been in daily contact via chat on how to promote the event and todos for making sure the experience is a great one for everyone. Getting module vendors involved (which helped the answer rate greatly) took 4 email campaigns, sending out Tweets to every vendor and answering questions by mail. Same goes for all the Magento developers who participated. Overall this takes close to 1 or 2 hours per day.

We will surely be back soon but April might not be doable as we would really like to enjoy our evenings off for at least a couple of weeks ;)
But no worries, we'll keep the Slack channels open and will continue to motivate people to join in so every day can be a MageStackDay!

See you soon on the next MageStcakDay and of course on the Magento StackExchange forum.

Comment: Sander. Thanks for your feedback.. I will try to online on stack day

Comment: Let me know. If  you guys need any help from me.I will always with yours

Comment: @AmitBera thanks for the offer. We might take you up on that next time :)

Comment: Thanks for your initiative, @AmitBera. We love organising MageStackDay, working and engaging with the community, but we need a break as this takes quite a lot of time next to our work. We'll be back with as much power as we can for another MageStackDay :-)

Answer (score 5):

Let's see how the stats shake out tomorrow. Looks like we made it to 75%.

Agreed that the effort is great (especially the organization!), but to be a site which StackExchange would be willing to convert from beta we will likely need to achieve and maintain >80% answer rate. This indicates not just the creation of answers but also ***upvoting those answers***. We need to put our thinking hats on for a way to motivate our userbase to upvote.

One thing which may help is the re-release of the official Magento forums, which are coming soon.

Comment: Ben ,i am agree with you on regarding on up vote of answers

Comment: Hey Ben, looking forward to the new forum. Can you give more info of what kind of forum it will be, what the goal is etc? :)

Answer (score 1):

MageStackDay is not the answer on the long term. MageStackDay is a great tool to draw a lot of attention towards the Magento SE on these few days and to get more people actively involved. You guys got me turned from a regular visitor into a daily active contributor!

As questions get more upvotes, comments and answers and in a shorter time, I believe that this will positively contribute to new users to return and stay active and for old inactive users to become active and involved again.

If you upvote other users, they will get notified of this and might visit more often. Besides it wil get them reputation points and that is great fun, especially if you get more of them and more often.

So not only try to upvote each other's questions but look around and start using those 40 upvote you have per day!